# Dropbox sdk for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have just found that Dropbox has updated his API's to v2 and older sdk is not working anymore.

It has been written that system requirements for new sdk is following:

```
iOS 9.0+
macOS 10.10+
Xcode 8+
```

Does that mean, I can no longer implement it for iOS 8? I know iOS8 is too old now and people might not be using it, just eager to know is there any way to implement it for iOS 8.

Link to Dropbox sdk readme file:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/blob/master/README.md#system-requirements

Answer (score 0):

The SDK itself doesn't support iOS 8, but you could see if any of the community SDKs satisfy your requirements:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks

Or, you can call the HTTPS endpoints directly:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation